# Counting HTML images with Python

Tags: python, operating-system, urllib

I need some feedback on how to count HTML images with Python 3.01 after extracting them, maybe my regular expression are not used properly.

Here is my code:

```
import re, os
import urllib.request
def get_image(url):
  url = 'http://www.google.com'
  total = 0
  try:
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    for line in f.readline():
      line = re.compile('<img.*?src="(.*?)">')
      if total > 0:
        x = line.count(total)
        total += x
        print('Images total:', total)

  except:
    pass
```

Comment: don't swallow the exception.  what does it raise?

Comment: hum well I could do an except: except urllib.error.HTTPError: if such url is not found

Comment: you are hiding the error it is throwing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points about your code:

1. It's much easiser to use a dedicated HTML parsing library to parse your pages (*that's the python way*).. I personally prefer [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
2. You're over-writing your `line` variable in the loop
3. `total` will always be 0 with your current logic
4. no need to compile your RE, as [it will be cached by the interpreter](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.compile)
5. you're discarding your exception, so no clues about what's going on in the code!
6. there could be other attributes to the `<img>` tags.. so your Regex is a little basic, also, use the `re.findall()` method to catch multiple instances on the same line...

changing your code around a little, I get:

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen

def get_image(url):

    total  = 0
    page   = urlopen(url).readlines()

    for line in page:

        hit   = re.findall('<img.*?>', str(line))
        total += len(hit)

    print('{0} Images total: {1}'.format(url, total))

get_image("http://google.com")
get_image("http://flickr.com")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this code is way better and I will take a note of your comments and try to install Beautiful Soup!

Comment: no problem.. don't forget to accept the answer if it's what you needed!  Take note of Corey's answer as well, that's a very good example of how simple these tasks are with Beautiful Soup!

Comment: Perfect! where this accept is located in this site, can't find it :(

Comment: There should be a tick at the side of the answer, under the up/down arrows and the answer's score

Answer (score 1):

using beautifulsoup4 (an html parser) rather than a regex:

```
import urllib.request

import bs4  # beautifulsoup4

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.imgur.com/').read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
images = soup.findAll('img')
print(len(images))
```

Comment: hum I can't do beautifulsoup4 in my IDLE, i get a traceback error.